# In Akka, is ActorContext thread safe?

Tags: thread-safety, akka

As per title, can an ActorContext extracted from within an actor be safely used from multiple threads (even those where the actor is not currently executing), for the creation of actors meant to be children of the original actor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. ActorContext is [not thread-safe](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala#L272) and shouldn't escape to other threads.

Comment: To the point, thank you. I sometimes find myself in situations where I need a resource to be owned by someone else but defined by the calling code, I've ended up passing Props to an actor and getting an ActorRef back using the ask pattern, is this a widely accepted pattern?

Comment: Sending Props is one way of doing it. I'd never block on the returned Future though, just do async composition.