# is it safe to close over the actor context in akka scheduler

Tags: scala, akka

I know that it's not safe to close over the `sender` method call or the internal state of the actor in a Future or a scheduler, but what about the actor context? what are in an `ActorContext`? Is it safe to close over the actor context in a scheduler or a future callback, like this? :

```scala
def receive: Receive = {
  case Msg => 
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1 second) {
       context.actorOf[ChildActor]
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it's safe to close over an Actor's state if it's immutable. I'm not sure if `context` is immutable. Even if it is, the closing over an context will send the context over a network if it's a remote actor (running in Akka cluster mode)

Comment: Well... No it's not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170557/in-akka-is-actorcontext-thread-safe

Comment: Better to have the scheduler send another message to `self` and then let the actor create that child.

Comment: @LMeyer - Sure, if it's not thread safe it shouldn't be closed over .

Comment: @Ryan - sending a message to self and then taking some action (in this case creating a new actor) is how I'm currently solving this issue my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not safe to close over an actor context.  From akka source:

```
/**
   * Stores the context for this actor, including self, and sender.
   * It is implicit to support operations such as `forward`.
   *
   * WARNING: Only valid within the Actor itself, so do not close over it and
   * publish it to other threads!
   *
   * [[akka.actor.ActorContext]] is the Scala API. `getContext` returns a
   * [[akka.actor.UntypedActorContext]], which is the Java API of the actor
   * context.
   */
implicit val context: ActorContext = { ...
```

Comment: Should have read the javadoc or source code more carefully. Thank you very much.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it is worth noting that there are some fields on the `ActorContext` that can be accessed in a thread-safe manner.